# My randomNumber generator play again acts weird

Tags: python-3.x

Now this is pretty beginner version of randomNumber guessing quiz code in Python. Many of you can look at it and make it 4 times shorter and I get it. However the point of this question is that I am unsure of the logic behind this problem.
If you execute this code, it will work just fine - till you get to Play again part.
When you type No - the program as intended quits. Yes starts again.
However if you type Yes first and the game goes one more time and you decide that it is for now I want to quit - this time you have to enter No twice.
And then it quits. I have no idea why. Ideas?

```
import random

def game(x,y):
    con = True
    count = 0
    ranNum = random.randint(x,y)
    while con:
        userInput = int(input("Take a guess between these numbers {} and {}: ".format(x,y)))
        count +=1
        if userInput == ranNum:
            print("You got it!")
            print("Number of tries: {}.".format(count))
            print("Play again?")
            while True:
                again = input("> ")
                if again.lower() == "yes":
                    game(x,y)
                elif again.lower() == "no":
                    con = False   
                    break
        elif userInput < ranNum:
            print("Wrong! Try higher!")
        elif userInput > ranNum:
            print("Wrong! Try lower!")

game(5,10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution: You need a break or return after calling game() when the user answers 'yes'.

This has an unfortunate side effect where each successive game adds another call to the stack. A better design would move the 'play again?' question out of the game function.

Comment: Having 'play again' outside was my first choice of how to approach this.
However I was wondering if it can be nested inside as well.
I will keep having play again outside of game functions from now on I suppose.
Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are running `game(x, y)` inside itself. Therefore,  `con` is a local variable. Think of it this way: when you type no the first time, it exits out of the `game(x, y)` that is running inside `game(x, y)` Therefore, the number of times you have played is the number of times you need to type no. An easier way to do this would be, like @xulfir says, put the `"Play again?"` loop outside of the function, or you could put `exit()` instead of using `break` to just kill the program.